# Javascript passing a string to create an object name (noob)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Okay, I have taken a tutorial to create an unnamed object in an array using a function
Given an array called contacts in which two named objects exist:

```
function add(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email) {

contacts[contacts.length] = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    email: email
    };
}

add("Buddy", "King", "312-555-5555", "buddy@email.biz");
```

that adds the unnamed object. But what do I do if I want to give the new object a name? I would like to use the first parameter )"Buddy" as the object name, so convert the string to ???

Comment: Give the object a name? It's a little unclear what you're asking. Could you post an example of a "named" object?

Comment: Are you trying to change an already existing entry? And find the entry by searching by first name?

Comment: Read about [javascript arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). It will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this (associative array):

```
contacts[firstName] = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    email: email
};
```

Now you can get the "Buddy" entry with `contacts['Buddy']`.
Note that all arrays in JS are associative but numbered arrays don't look much like it.

Comment: Not to be too literal, but there's no such thing as associative arrays. There are Arrays and there are Objects. Arrays are Objects. Objects have properties. There's almost never a good reason to set properties (that aren't numeric) on Arrays. Arrays are meant to be used with numeric indexes and the specific methods provided (`push`, `pop`, etc.) that manipulate the internal representation of data (reflected in the `length` property). I think your solution is ideal, but `contacts` should be an object literal (`{}`), not an array (`[]`)

Comment: @Ian: Thank you for pointing this out. I didn't want to go into details about objects, objects with array behaviour and apparent arrays that lack array behaviour (such as `arguments`) and further intrinsics you can look up in Crockford's *Good parts*. And of course, `contacts = {};`. The difference is here that JS has only associativity (from an arbitrary key to an object) and never has an actual index (or address offset, such as in C and C++). In that sense, all objects use associativity and therefore arrays do too. But that's already too long for a comment :)

Comment: Thanks, finally getting comfortable with JS language, so now I know what you meant!

Comment: I'm guessing that what I ought to be doing is creating a prototype, then making a new instance of the prototype (the Buddy object).